# Does the initializer list only accept initializing variables with values of the same type?

Tags: c++

I have a class with a string as a member. My code successfully assigned a `char` to it in the body of the constructor.

However, when I tried using initializer list, it showed a confusing error: "no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list". Alas, I'm not sure whether my assumption, which is in the topic, is true or false.

This is my experiment code:

```
class A
{
    string str;
public:
    A(char character);
};

A::A(char character): str(character)
{}
```

Comment: Did you add `#include <string>`?

Answer (score 1):

If you consult a reference like this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

You will see that there is no std::string constructor which takes a single char.  There is, however, a constructor which takes a count and a char, so you can do this:

```
A::A(char character)
    : str(1, character)
```

Comment: Alternatively, there is an `operator=` that takes a single `char`: `A::A(char character) { str = character; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That was already mentioned in the second sentence of the question.